# How to get data from another data base in runtime

Tags: grails, runtime, datasource

I need an optimal way to change Database in run-time, whether from hibernate or from JNDI or another. I need to change the database when a user clicks on a specific button (Change dependencies on events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Grails 1.3.x you can to use the  [Burt Beckwith's Datasources plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/datasources), in Grails 2.x [that feature has been added to core](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources).

Then you can to use a parameter to pass database connection name

```
def database = params.database
if(!database) database = "default"
```

and to use [Groovy dynamic method invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy) to call it

```
def zipCode = ZipCode.'${database}'.get(42)
…
zipCode.'${database}'.save()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is my data source name

datasource(name: 'database2') {...}

can I call this datasource as if(!database) database = "database2"