# Grails Change Datasource (JDBC URL) at runtime

Tags: grails, jdbc

I want to change my default (and only) datasource (jdbc url, username, password) in a view. These changes should immediatly affect the connections.

There are currently no answers that fit my needs.

I'm stuck using this in my controller:

```
dataSourceUnproxied.with {
  url = params.jdbc
  username = params.user
  password = params.password
}
```

But the connections are still pointing to the old datasource.

How can I reset the current data source and use the new properties (using Grails 1.3.7)?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? All I've seen is defining multiple dataSources, but I dont wan't that - I want to CHANGE one (or several) properties of an already defined dataSource programmatically. And I'm unable to find an answer.

Comment: @Pere No, I'm sorry. I never found a solution for this. I've used a naive configuration management while deploying my app which then sets the appropriate urls. But it is not possible (and not needed anymore) to change the urls at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can to use the [datasource plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/datasources) to create a new datasource for that view and change it dynamically if you need. Check it: [grails how to get data from another data base in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235656/grails-how-to-get-data-from-another-data-base-in-runtime/12236129#12236129)